# Selenium python script can't run after an update to chrome browser

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

The problem occurs in my python script run on an ubuntu server (no GUI). A chrome browser version 112 was installed on this server, and other requirements (chromedriver, python, etc.) were all met and a python3 script worked fine. Its function is calling webdriver, manipulating chrome to do some automated work.

But after an update to chrome browser a few days ago, the script don't work now, and I got an error like this:

```
DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

I tried to add '--no-sandbox' and many other options (in ChromeOption), but they never work.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Answering my question. The key problem comes from an option: `--user-data-dir`. Maybe the problem also related to `--headless` mode.

I'm using these two chrome-options, like this:

```py
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=chrome-userdata')
```

Another post mentioned that such error message may comes from running chrome in headful mode (no --headless option), but on an OS without GUI. So I try removing `--headless=new` first. Then I run this script again, it start a chrome window on my remote computer (I'm using ubuntu desktop and enable an X11 option, so that this works for me).

By running this, new data and configuration are written in user-data-dir. So next time I recover the commented `--headless=new` option, It works as it used to be.

Hope my experience may help you.